# Stored Procedure Using way more memory than expected

Tags: mysql, memory, stored-procedures

I have built a stored procedure that builds a memory temporary table `A` and then fills this with data by looping through the results of a standard cursor. Data is selected into the temporary table via several joins from other MyISAM tables that I have in my database. The SP works correctly, but it was running up against a full table memory limit. To solve this I cranked the memory limit up:

```
set @@tmp_table_size=127108864; (121MEGs)
set @@max_heap_table_size=127108864; (121MEGs)
```

This is about what is took to get my SP to run successfully. This seems odd to me because the table `A` that is created and returned (via a select * from A) is only 16MEGs in size. I'm not sure what is causing the other part of the memory requirement, which is about 100MEGs. It seems like the SP is using way more memory than needed. My guess is that the joins that are run in the SP as part of the cursor loop are leaving their temp tables behind after they run and that these are not being cleaned up until after the SP finishes execution. This would mean that a huge stack of joined temp tables is floating in memory. Is there any way to stop this or to verify that the extra memory is being sucked up by these joins run inside the SP cursor loop? Could this memory suck be coming from something else? Thank you to anyone who helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

depending on your queries mysql can create several temporary tables, so - use EXPLAIN EXTENDED on each of your query to find what creates it

Comment: Will do. Thanks. Any idea I what to do when I find the offending query?

Comment: Optimize it, create indexes, re-structure db, re-think architecture at all, there is no one solution :(

Comment: I know :`( You are right. I'm just a man at the office too late with more hope than sleep. Thank you all the same.